# COM Exception HRESULT 0x800AC472 when calling Excel.Worksheet.Open function

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, office-interop

I cannot to open Excel file neither ".xls" nor ".xlsx"
Book1.xlsx is a sample file which it is a blank sheet.

```
      Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
      Dim wBook1 As Excel.Workbook
      excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx", False, False)
```

If Excel.Workbooks.Open() function is called, it will get the error.

**Error Message**

```
          COM exception HRESULT: 0x800AC472.
```

Comment: I think , you must reinstall excel app.

Comment: if you try just excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx") still the same result?

Comment: Is the File already opened? Is something *interacting* with it? Do you have a dialog open? The License dialog, maybe, which will block an Excel instance before it's shown? Or, is there something selected in a worksheet of the same workbook? Not opened: have you checked,in Task Manager, whether you have previous instances of Excel that you haven't released?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your suggestion.  It cannot to open because Sheet1 is opening. But I don't understand. If I create new instance of the Excel.Application, it will create Sheet1 automatically.

Comment: can you open the file specified manually? or do you get any error messages as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. It cannot to open because Sheet1 is opening. It will show saving dialog.
So I must force close all sheets in the workbook.

```
     Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
      If Not excelApp Is Nothing Then
          For Each wb As Excel.Workbook In excelApp.Workbooks
              wb.Close(False)
          Next
              excelApp.Quit()
      End If
```

But I don't understand.
Everytime when I create new instance of Excel.Application, It will create a Sheet1 automatically. Why?